# Abstraction for asynchronous computation that cannot fail

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future, scalaz

Scala `Futures` are a fine abstraction for asynchronous computation that can fail. What abstraction should I use when I know that there is no failure possible?

Here is a concrete use case:

```
case class Service123Error(e: Throwable)

val f1: Future[User] =
  service123.call()

val f2: Future[Either[Service123Error, User]] =
  f1.map(Right.apply)
    .recover { case e => Left(Service123Error(e)) }
```

In this code, the types do not model the fact that `f2` always successfully completes. Given several values similar to `f2`, I know I can `Future.sequence` over them (i.e. without the fail fast behavior), but the types are not carrying this information.

Comment: Unrelated: Quoting the [`Either` ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Either): *Convention dictates that `Left` is used for failure and `Right` is used for success*.

Comment: I always mess that up... Fixed

Comment: If `service123.call()` cannot fail, what does type Service123Error reppresent? Also, the Future API represents failure and success with the  `scala.util.{Success, Failure}` types...if you map `Failure` to an `Either` it is not really about the Future API anymore, no?

Comment: `service123.call()` can fail, but `f2` cannot since it catches all errors with the `recover`. My with `Future[Either]` is that it as 3 options, `Future.failed(e)`, `Future.successful(Left(l))` and `Future.successful(Right(r))`, with 3 different meaning, I would like to get ride of the first option.

Comment: Since `f2` is async computation a failure _is_ possible. If you only consider a specific error inside `system123` as recoverable (normally catch all is not a good sign) I would probably change signature of `system123.call` to `Either[..., User]`.

Comment: What does async has to do with failure? Do you consider that `Future(1 to 1000000 reduce (_++_))` can fail?

Comment: Maybe not in such simple case (unless an exception is thrown by `ExecutionContext` for some reason), but as I understand it `Future` always implies a possibility of failure since it potentially runs in a separate thread and exceptions do happen. `.map` and `.recover` create new futures, so `f2` may run in a separate thread from `f1` and from main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would not stick an `Either` into a `Future` if it carries the error information. Simply use the failure side of the future.

```
Future(Right(User))           -> Future[User](User)
Future(Left(Service123Error)) -> Future[User](throw Service123Error)
```

Comment: That the point of my question, if it was a `Future[T, Service123Error]`, why not, but with `Future[T, Throwable]` I cannot encode in the type the fact that I'm dealing with a `Service123Error` and not any exception... Also `Future.sequence` does not work a in your example (it fails fast on the first exception).

Comment: You can pattern match on the failure values and distinguish as many different types of errors as you wish!

Comment: `Throwable` is not a sealed trait I control, so it's like giving up on type safety. I don't wan't to have `case _ => ???` hanging out all over my code.

Comment: Well, that's what you've got with the Future API. I still recommend you to use this with pattern matching instead of cluttering your types unnecessarily for a bit of more type safety.